# Expo app suddenly not reloading on saved work and also instead of giving red screen error it crashes

Tags: expo

I am working on an expo app and it was working all good but suddenly it stops reloading whenever I save my work and also whenever there is a error in my app it simply crashes instead of throwing that red screen with error due to which it is very difficult to debug the code.

Comment: Did check terminal/debug  logs?

Comment: No logs are displaying......very rarely some error is displayed but earlier it was not like that don't know what happen suddenly...also it doesn't respond to save work.